# How scanf works ? Keyboard buffer?

Tags: c, char, int, scanf

I want to know how `scanf` works. Difference In working of `scanf` when dealing with integer input and character input.

```
 int main()
 {
    int x , y ;
    printf("Enter A Number  x : ");
    scanf("%d" , &x);
    printf("Enter Any Number Y : ");
    scanf("%d" , &y);

    return 0;
    }
```

In The Above Program Output is Enter A Number X : I enter a number .Then it 
again ask for any number y. I enter that number and program terminates.

But in the program written below it ask for character . I enter a 
character. After That it again ask for a character, but it terminates without giving me an option to enter a character .

```
int main()
   {  
    char x , y ;
    printf("Enter A char  x : ");
    scanf("%c" , &x);
    printf("Enter Any char Y : ");
    scanf("%c" , &y);

    return 0;
    }
```

I know that when I entered first character and pressed enter .
That enter get stored in the keyboard buffer memory and next `scanf` takes that value in and does not let me enter it.

But Why does this thing not happen in integer case ?

Comment: Can you format the code (fix the indentation)?

Comment: @sashoalm Done . I have Got The Answer.